# How do I assign multiple textures into single a mesh in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, textures, graphics

First example: 
You can take a huge rock shaped mesh and put a tiled rock texture all over it.
Now, some places needs to be covered with a grass texture (or other vegetation).

Another example:
Usually, terrain are built from tiled textures. In order to achieve a less "tilly" look, you can apply 4 times bigger (or 16 and so on..) tiled texture on it, and by that you'll gain a nice "random" tiled texture (seen that in the UDK's docs).

Blender (the 3d graphics app) is OpenGL based, and it allows you to assign multiple materials to a single mesh.

How can i do it in my own OpenGL application?
Thanks,
 Amir

P.S:
I'm looking for a better solution than rendering 50 tris with tex a and and 3 more tris with tex b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called *multitexturing*.  Modern graphics cards have several texture units that each can sample a different texture.  When you render your rock you specify vertices that have UV coordinates for each texture you want to render.

In OpenGL you can use `glActiveTexture` to [select](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml) your active texture unit so that you can bind a texture to it and use it in subsequent rendering.  Your vertices will need additional texture coordinate pairs; one pair per texture you intend to render.

The modern way to do multitexturing is using shaders (GLSL in OpenGL typically). Load and bind each texture to a different texture unit, set your shader uniforms to the value of the texture units (0 for texture unit 0 etc) you're using, sample each texture, and blend using the desired blending function to get your output color.

Comment: How can i tell which chunk of tris should be rendered with texture a and which should be rendered with texture b?

Comment: Thanks.. I've looked how its done, and its exactly as you said :)